Solution of a system of differential equations by the Laplace method
Original system of differential equations:
\begin{cases}
\dot{p_{2}}(t)=\mu p_{1}(t)-\lambda p_{2}(t)\\
\dot{p_{1}}(t)=\lambda p_{2}(t)-(\mu+\lambda)p_{1}(t)\\
\dot{p_{0}}(t)=\lambda p_{1}(t)\\
p_{2}(0)=1\\
p_{1}(0)=0\\
p_{0}(0)=0
\end{cases}
My solution:
\begin{cases}
pP_{2}(p)-P_{2}(0)=\mu P_{1}(p)-\lambda P_{2}(p)\\
pP_{1}(p)-P_{1}(0)=\lambda P_{2}(p)-(\mu+\lambda)P_{1}(p)\\
pP_{0}(p)-P_{0}(0)=\lambda P_{1}(p)\\
P_{2}(0)=1\\
P_{1}(0)=0\\
P_{0}(0)=0
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
pP_{2}(p)-1=\mu P_{1}(p)-\lambda P_{2}(p)\\
pP_{1}(p)=\lambda P_{2}(p)-(\mu+\lambda)P_{1}(p)\\
pP_{0}(p)=\lambda P_{1}(p)
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
P_{2}(p)(p+\lambda)-\mu P_{1}(p)=1\\
P_{1}(p)(p+\mu+\lambda)-\lambda P_{2}(p)=0\\
pP_{0}(p)=\lambda P_{1}(p)
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
P_{2}(p)(p+\lambda)-\mu\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}=1\\
\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}(p+\mu+\lambda)-\lambda P_{2}(p)=0\\
\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}=P_{1}(p)
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
P_{2}(p)\lambda(p+\lambda)-\mu pP_{0}(p)=\lambda\\
pP_{0}(p)(p+\mu+\lambda)-\lambda^{2}P_{2}(p)=0\\
\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}=P_{1}(p)
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
P_{2}(p)\lambda^{2}(p+\lambda)-\lambda\mu pP_{0}(p)=\lambda^{2}(1)\\
pP_{0}(p)(p+\mu+\lambda)(p+\lambda)-\lambda^{2}P_{2}(p)(p+\lambda)=0(2)\\
\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}=P_{1}(p)
\end{cases}
$(1)+(2):pP_{0}(p)(p+\mu+\lambda)(p+\lambda)-\lambda\mu pP_{0}(p)=\lambda^{2}$
$P_{0}(p)(p^{2}+p(\mu+2\lambda))p=\lambda^{2}$
$P_{0}(p)=\frac{\lambda^{2}}{p^{2}(p+\mu+2\lambda)}$
$\frac{1}{(p+a)(p+b)^{2}}\doteqdot\frac{e^{-at}-e^{-bt}(1-(a-b)t)}{(a-b)^{2}}$
$b=0:\frac{1}{(p+a)p^{2}}\doteqdot\frac{e^{-at}+at-1}{a^{2}}$
$p_{0}(t)=\lambda^{2}\frac{e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t}+(\mu+2\lambda)t-1}{(\mu+2\lambda)^{2}}$
$P_{1}(p)=\frac{pP_{0}(p)}{\lambda}=\frac{p}{\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{2}}{p^{2}(p+\mu+2\lambda)}=\frac{\lambda}{p(p+\mu+2\lambda)}$
$\frac{1}{p(p+a)}\doteqdot\frac{1}{a(1-e^{-at})}$
$p_{1}(t)=\frac{\lambda}{(\mu+2\lambda)(1-e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t})}$
$P_{2}(p)(p+\lambda)-\mu P_{1}(p)=1$
$P_{2}(p)=\frac{1}{p+\lambda}+\frac{\mu}{p+\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{p(p+\mu+2\lambda)}=\frac{1}{p+\lambda}+\frac{\mu\lambda}{p(p+\mu+2\lambda)(p+\lambda)}$
$\frac{1}{p(p+a)(p+b)}\doteqdot\frac{1}{b-a}(\frac{e^{-bt}}{b}-\frac{e^{-at}}{a})$
$p_{2}(t)=\frac{1}{\mu+2\lambda-\lambda}(\frac{e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t}}{\mu+2\lambda}-\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda})=\frac{1}{\mu+\lambda}(\frac{e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t}}{\mu+2\lambda}-\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda})$
Total: $p_{0}(t)=\lambda^{2}\frac{e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t}+(\mu+2\lambda)t-1}{(\mu+2\lambda)^{2}}$, $p_{1}(t)=\frac{\lambda}{(\mu+2\lambda)(1-e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t})}$, $p_{2}(t)=\frac{1}{\mu+\lambda}(\frac{e^{-(\mu+2\lambda)t}}{\mu+2\lambda}-\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda})$
In sum, $p_{0}(t)$, $p_{1}(t)$, $p_{2}(t)$ should give 1, as I understand, but this does not happen. Please tell me where I made a mistake in the solution?

For calculations I used the following table of Laplace transforms:


The Laplace transform of $\dot{p}_2(t)$ is $pP_2(p) - p_2(0)$.

The mistake is in the transition from the line:
$$ (1) + (2): pP_0(p)(p+\mu+\lambda)(p+\lambda) - \lambda\mu p P_0(p) = \lambda^2
$$
to the next line:
$$
P_0(p)(p^2 + p(\mu + 2\lambda))p= \lambda^2
$$
But it should be:
$$
P_0(p)(p^2+p(\mu+2\lambda)+\lambda^2)p=\lambda^2
$$
Also, I didn't understand why you checked $p_0(t)+p_1(t)+p_2(t)=1$. This equation will be satisfied for $t=0$, but not for arbitrary $t$.
